# How to center a table in html5 css3?

Tags: html, css

Like if a have two tables and want one table only in the middle of a web page what should I do then?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: horizontally centered? vertically centered? both?

Answer (score -2):

try to use the Css grid. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3LRtAm2SOo) is a documentation about it on Youtube.